Are device integrity checks built in to Android Enterprise Recaptcha?
I'm confused by the following in the Play Integrity API documentation:
"reCAPTCHA Enterprise automatically includes Play Integrity API signals, and combines them with reCAPTCHA network and application signals for customers, providing a frictionless, invisible fraud management solution out of the box."
Currently my app is using Enterprise Recaptcha, retrieving a score from the API and sending it to the backend server which does a simple check to see if the score passes a threshold. I want to integrate device integrity checks but I'm unsure if that's already part of the score returned by Recaptcha, or if I need to additionally request a Play Integrity token and validate that on the backend server as well.
I ask because we recently faced credential stuffing attacks which likely came from illegitimate devices and are looking to a way to prevent this and validate requests are coming from a valid device.
